# I want to preserve the specific folders, but don't download from git repo

Tags: git, github

I have some folders where is downloaded by developers when they set up the development environment for the first time and doesn't have to be re-download. How can I set this folder for satisfying this requirements in the Git?

① First time when the developer commands "git clone ", the folder have to be downloaded.

② When they set up the development environment, the folder have to be ignored however they changes.

There are so many files in the folders. Whenever I use command git commit/push, it occurs so many conflicts.

Comment: Sorry, the question is difficult to understand due to the wording.  I realize English might not be your first language.  Could you perhaps provide an example of the problem?  Maybe cut & paste the Git commands and their outputs?

Comment: Yes,  English is not my first language. I did my best making my question for you to  approach easily. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make sure I understand the situation, let me use a concrete example.  Let's say the project has a folder that contains images.  `project/img/`  The user can add their own images to that folder, and they can change the existing ones.  You don't want the user's additions and changes to the images pushed.

Making that work with Git gets ugly.  One way is to use `git update-index --assume-unchanged project/img/*` to tell Git that changes to individual files should be ignored, but it cannot be done for a directory.  And it has to be done by every user.  And it has to be done again every time a new file is added to that folder.

A better option is to add the folder to `.gitignore`.  When changes need to be made to files in that folder, `git add -f` can be used to force their addition.  This is error prone for the developers, but at least makes it not a problem for the users.

The best solution is to use two different folders.  One for the default images which come with the project.  Another for any extra or replacement images from the user.  Add that user image folder to your `.gitignore` file.  This works best with how Git works.  This also lets the user tell what images they added and changed, versus those that came with the project, and they can safely control the whole folder.

Comment: I appreciate your help. It's great :)